# boostrap component (for date,month,year in three dropdowns) sompylasar/bootstrap-datepicker-select css not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the component https://github.com/sompylasar/bootstrap-datepicker-select

I need three dropdowns for date, month, year like this component has (if you look in index.html) and when you open this example it works, but when i tried to implement it works as it should (js part), except css doesnt work (it isnt as in example), now i know i included all css and js files. And also ive tried with his bootstrap css (which he included) and then it works (dropdowns look like his), but it disrupts all my other pages.Now for my question, is there a simple solution to fix this problem (im new to bootstrap),or is there another component for the same thing or should i just take standard dropdowns and fill them with date, month, year with foreach. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i went with the classic approach with foreach

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="selectDate">Date of Birth:</label>
                        <select id="selectDate" style="width:auto;" class="form-control selectWidth">
                            @for ($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++)
                            <option class="">{{$i}}</option>
                            @endfor
                        </select>
                        <select id="selectMonth" style="width:auto;" class="form-control selectWidth">
                            @for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++)
                            <option class="">{{$i}}</option>
                            @endfor
                        </select>
                        <select id="selectYear" style="width:auto;" class="form-control selectWidth">
                            @for ($i = 1900; $i <= 2015; $i++)
                            <option class="">{{$i}}</option>
                            @endfor
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

If anyone figures out that plugin please write it in comments or as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Pick Year</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-select@1.12.4/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" type="text/css" />
      <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.2.0/css/datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="//unpkg.com/jquery@3.4.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script> 
      <script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
      <script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-select@1.12.4/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script> 
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.2.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="datepicker" id="datepicker" />
      <script>
         $("#datepicker").datepicker({
             format: "yyyy",
             viewMode: "years",
             minViewMode: "years",
             autoclose:true 
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```